# Parsing a mix of Backward slash and forward slash in a filename

Tags: python

I am getting filename from an api in this format containing mix of `/` and `\`.

infilename = 'c:/mydir1/mydir2\mydir3\mydir4\123xyz.csv'

When I try to parse the directory structure, `\` followed by a character is converted into single character.

Is there a way around to get each component correctly?

What I already tried:

```
path.normpath didn't help. 

infilename = 'c:/mydir1/mydir2\mydir3\mydir4\123xyz.csv'
os.path.normpath(infilename)

out:
'c:\\mydir1\\mydir2\\mydir3\\mydir4Sxyz.csv'
```

Comment: `normpath()` won't help if you don't have a literal backslash in the string -- in that case, it was removed by the parser, and isn't there for that or any other function call to fix. And that's the thing -- if you want to write a literal backslash in a regular single-quoted Python string, you need to double it: `'\\'` is a string containing a single backslash, whereas `'\'` isn't a valid Python string at all (it's the *start* of a string containing a literal `'` character, but it's not closed, because the ending quote is escaped by the backslash literal).

Comment: please print the result of the string returned by your API instead of leading us into believing you're typing a literal string, which is clearly not the case.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I'm under the impression that the problem is not about literal strings, whatever my answer was...

Comment: Bingo! Now it's not about raw strings _at all_. What do you mean by "parse directory structure"? must be in some code we don't see.

Comment: `'c:\\mydir1\\mydir2\\mydir3\\mydir4Sxyz.csv'` is **exactly right**. If you `print(os.path.normpath(infilename))`,  you'll see that each of those `\\`s is actually just one slash.

Answer (score 1):

use r before the string to process it as a raw string (i.e. no string formatting).

e.g.

```
infilename = r'C:/blah/blah/blah.csv'
```

More details here:
https://docs.python.org/3.6/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-and-bytes-literals

Comment: that raw prefix is useless with slashes... it achieves nothing.

Comment: Might clarify that (as "useless with *forward* slashes"). "Useless with slashes" is a bit overbroad.

Comment: infilename is coming to me as variable name. How can I make a string into raw string?

Comment: yeah, forward slashes. No need to escape those.

Comment: @learner, if it was already parsed, *it's too late*; the original text is gone, and only the result of parsing it is left.

Comment: @learner if it's coming from an API, no need to "rawify" them. raw prefix is only for _literals_. So I bet that your question is not that clear now.

Answer (score 1):

that's not visible in your example but writing this:

```
infilename = 'c:/mydir1/mydir2\mydir3\mydir4\123xyz.csv'
```

isn't a good idea because some of the lowercase (and a few uppercase) letters are interpreted as escape sequences if following an antislash. Notorious examples are `\t`, `\b`, there are others. For instance:

```
infilename = 'c:/mydir1/mydir2\thedir3\bigdir4\123xyz.csv'
```

doubly fails because 2 chars are interpreted as "tab" and "backspace".

When dealing with literal Windows-style path (or regexes), you have to use the *raw* prefix, and better, normalize your path to get rid of the slashes.

```
infilename = os.path.normpath(r'c:/mydir1/mydir2\mydir3\mydir4\123xyz.csv')
```

However, the raw prefix only applies to *literals*. If the returned string appears, when printing `repr(string)`, as `'the\terrible\\dir'`, then tab chars have already been put in the string, and there's nothing you can do except a lousy post-processing.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of parsing by `\` try parsing by `\\`. You usually have to escape by `\` so the \ character is actually `\\`.